# How to add all the marks from same id in python

Tags: python, csv, data-analysis

Iam trying to read from the csv file in python and then check if the sum of all the weights of every test in a particular course should add up to 100.If it doesn't it should display an error message .

[image]

Comment: Okay, cool. What parts of this can you do already? Do you know how to ingest CSV files? Have you tried anything? Are you using a library like Pandas? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

### With `pandas`:

Try `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
print(df.groupby('course_id')['weight'].sum().ge(100).all())
```

It will return `True` (like in this case) if all the grouped and summed values equal to or greater than `100`, but if not, it would give `False`.

If you really want to raise an error, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
if not df.groupby('course_id')['weight'].sum().ge(100).all():
    raise ValueError('Error Message!')
```